# sublime text swap line keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use the swap line keyboard shortcuts in sublime text 2.

I'm holding down command, ctrl, and up and down keys, but they're not doing anything.

Using the edit menu item works though. I'm using a small mac keyboard. What could be the problem thanks.

```
[{
  "keys": ["ctrl+super+up"],
  "command": "swap_line_up"
}, {
  "keys": ["ctrl+super+down"],
  "command": "swap_line_down"
}

]
```

Answer (score 56):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd>/<kbd>⇩</kbd> on OS 10.8 running sublime text 2 do swap lines for me, by default. I did not need to bind any specific keys, nor does it appear to have any other function.

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me. Sublime 3, I've never gotten it to work though edit menu is fine. Strange.

Comment: It might be conflicting with a bundle that you have installed, which has the same keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Confirmed to work on 10.11.4 with Sublime 3 Build 3103 without doing any edits to key bindings.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd>/<kbd>⇩</kbd> (on linux)

Answer (score 5):

Mac OSX 10.8, Sublime 3, small Mac keyboard:

Default behaviour didn't work for me, but then I copied the lines from  `Preferences > Key Bindings - Default` to `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`. The moment I saved the user settings file, the keyboard shortcuts for swapping lines started to work.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `cmd+up/down` on the small mac keyboard bind to something else? I don't recall what up and down do, but I think left and right bind to home and end respectively.

Well anyways, to check, in the console enter `sublime.log_input(True)` then press the keys. It should tell you what key presses ST is actually receiving. If that is correct, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` into the console to ensure the proper command is running. You can also try running https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts to see if anything else is bound to that key combination in general. Disclaimer - I'm the author of FindKeyConflicts.

Comment: Running `sublime.log_input(True)` helped me realize I was entering `alt+super+[` which is what Xcode's default swap lines shortcut is and what I'm used to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra - Sublime Text 3:

I have problem at the default configuration “CMD + CTRL + Up arrow/Down arrow”, doesn’t work for me.
Then I edit my User Key Bindings (Preferences > Key Bindings > User) and add this:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" },
]
```

It’s works for me using “CTRL + ATL + Up arrow/Down arrow”